# how to return buffer to a streamablefile in nestjs !? the error occured is Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Buffer'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

**The description:** I can't return a StreamableFile from buffer , i've tried `buffer.from` but doesn't work which shows the error below

**French version of issue:**
Aucune surcharge ne correspond à cet appel.
La surcharge 1 sur 2, '(buffer: Buffer): StreamableFile', a généré l'erreur suivante.
L'argument de type 'string' n'est pas attribuable au paramètre de type 'Buffer'.
La surcharge 2 sur 2, '(readable: Readable): StreamableFile', a généré l'erreur suivante.
L'argument de type 'string' n'est pas attribuable au paramètre de type 'Readable'.ts(2769).

**English Version of issue:**
No overload matches this call.
The 1 of 2 overload, '(buffer: Buffer): StreamableFile', generated the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Buffer'.
The 2 of 2 overload, '(readable: Readable): StreamableFile', generated the following error.
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Readable'.ts(2769)

```
async FindCommands(@Res({ passthrough: true }) response, @Query() query: DateRangQueryVm): Promise<StreamableFile> {
    const filesToPdf= await this.commandsService.getCommands(query.startDate, query.endDate);
    
    const nommation= `commands.pdf`;

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', `application/pdf`);
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${nommation}`);
    
    Buffer.from(filesToPdf, 'utf-8');
    return new StreamableFile(filesToPdf);
  };
```

return new **StreamableFile(**filesToPdf**);**

**link to nest documentation:**
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files#streaming-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicitly clear: you can't pass a `string` to `StreamableFile`, you have to pass either a `Buffer` or a `Readable`. To create a buffer from a string, you can use `return new StreamableFile(Buffer.from(filesToPdf))`